# Update column value based on PHP variable which is equal to a column name

Tags: php, mysql

```
$rating =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['rating']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE table SET $rating=$rating+1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

Is there any way to update a column based on the PHP variable `$rating`? `$rating` is a column name.

Also, this may be prone to security risks etc, so I'd like to know if this is even a good way to go about it.

Comment: $rating is the variable name. It has values only. If you store column name as value in $rating you will use the above query.

Comment: It's not working. For example if `$rating = "silver"` then I need it to be `SET silver=silver+1`.

Comment: $rating is not column name of table. So you will defenetly mention the column name like SET `column_name` = $rating + 1

Comment: @VigneshBala: The OP wants to increment the field defined by `$rating`, which can be done as `SET some_field=some_field+1` in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use variable name as field name in the sql. However you must validate it first before putting it into sql string. Since its not a field value, you cannot "quote" it.

```
$rating =  $_POST['rating'];
// Define list of valid "rating" db field names here
$valid_fields = Array('rating_a', 'rating_b', 'rating_c');

if (in_array($rating, $valid_fields)) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE table SET $rating=$rating+1 WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Validating the column variable didn't work for me with PDO. I tried various arrangements of brackets around the '$colname+1' scenario, but they all gave errors. Finally I opted for SELECTING the current value, incrementing it and putting it back.

```
//  Find existing value:
    $query = "SELECT " . $col . " from " . $table . "
        WHERE bk_ref = :bk_ref";

    echo 'Select query is: ' . $query . ' with bk_ref: ' . $bk_ref . '<br />';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(['bk_ref' => $bk_ref]);

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo 'Row is: '; print_r ($row); echo '<br />';
    $val = $row[$col];
    echo 'Found value: ' . $val . '<br />';
// Could use FETCH_NUM, $val would be at $row[0]

// Increment by 1 (or make any other changes required):    
    $val++;

//  Put it back into the table:
    $query1 = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET " . $col . " = " . $val . "
        WHERE bk_ref = :bk_ref";

    echo 'Update query is: ' . $query1 . ' with bk_ref: ' . $bk_ref . '<br />';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
    $stmt->execute(['bk_ref' => $bk_ref]);
```

I am aware that this doesn't precisely answer the question and might be regarded as 'old school', but it does at least provide a reasonably concise solution, once the 'echoes' and comments are taken out.

Comment: Sorry to say, this is not "old school" but just unacceptable. If you cannot create a simple SQL query, that's fair: we all learn. But at least you can keep this code to yourself.

Comment: Also it's hard to understand why didn't you check the accepted answer where no whatever "brackets" around $colname+1 can be clearly seen.

Answer (score -3):

First and foremost your sql is not correct because  I don't think a variable can be a column name in mysql. So please check in the mysql database for the exact column you want to update. So your sql will be something like

```
$rating =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['rating']) + 1;

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `table` SET `rating`=$rating WHERE id='$id'");
```

If rating is not your column name then change it to the exact column name. 
Hope I helped.

Comment: That's not what I want, but I think I may be able to construct an if/else if statement based on the $rating they gave and do separate queries. I was just wondering if there was a quicker method to do it

Comment: It is possible to achieve validate variable column names and execute a SQL query like stated in the answer.